# How to build React native IOS app for internal distribution without using Expo.dev

Tags: react-native

I have started building internal distribution IOS app using expo and it works ,but after free version takes hours to build one and paid version is too expensive for a developer. I have used visual studio code as IDE. Couldnt find any details on how to build manually . Any help would be highly appreciated.

Using Expo cli takes ages as below

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/build/internal-distribution/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run builds in your own machine by using

```
eas build --platform ios --local --profile=myProfile
```

More info in their documentation:
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/local-builds/